# Is there a way to increase the Google Console API project creation limit?

Tags: android, google-api, android-c2dm

I am working on getting OAuth keys for c2dm push messaging.  In order to do that I am creating a separate Google Console Api Project for each app.

The problem is is that I have to do around 100 Android Apps and I keep running into the following message in the Google API Console when trying to create a new project.

> You have reached your daily limit for creating projects. Try again tomorrow.

This is really slowing my team down and this could be a reoccurring problem since we produce many apps sometimes in quick succession.  We would be happy to pay for the greater capacity but have no idea where to request them to increase the limit for this.  There is nothing evident in the page that helps me to up this limit.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new project for each app, and in fact I don't think it makes sense to do so.  The purpose of the OAuth key (or ClientLogin credentials) is to authenticate the sender email that you signed up for C2DM with.  If you're using the same sender for all 100 apps, then you only need one OAuth key.  If you're signing up for C2DM separately with 100 different sender addresses, then each of those can create a new API project. Either way, you won't have to worry about the daily project creation limit.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, this process has so little documentation it's hard to get everything right.